# Using SUMPRODUCT, INDEX and MATCH, How to find the maximum value by product type?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below data:

(I have attached two Images as RAW DATA)

SALES DATA

[image: REVENUE DATA]

SALES MIX:

[image: SALES MIX]

Which of the products- A,B,C,D was sold the most by value? Considering the sales data starts from column A till D and Sales mix from F till I. How can I solve this in excel.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(G8:J8),MAX(K8:N8))
```

This is what I tried. This returns the max value but I want to label with the correct product type.

Comment: If you are data is starting from Column A till D for Sales and for Mix from F till I then your formula the one you have tried is not matching `=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(G8:J8),MAX(K8:N8)) `

Comment: Isn't the percentages over the year and the sales values over quarters, so no matter what value the sales show, you can see solely by the percentage which product sold most (by value). So Q1 of the first data row sold 43% * 352,000 for product A and 21% * 352,000 for B, etc